# Using Signalr In dnn

Tags: signalr, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am using signalr library in my DotnetNuke module.
Currently I have inserted the follwing record to hostsettings table in DNN DB

```
insert into hostsettings
(SettingName
, SettingValue
, SettingIsSecure 
, CreatedByUserId
, CreatedOnDate
, LastModifiedByUserId
, LastModifiedOnDate
)
values(
'AUM_DoNotRewriteRegEx'
,'/DesktopModules/|/Providers|/LinkClick\.aspx|/SignalR'
, 0
, -1
, GETDATE()
, -1
, GETDATE()
)
```

So when i access my module using this url it works fine.
(http://dnndev.me/ChatModule)

But when i created a Child portal and add the module and tried to access using (http://dnndev.me/p3/ChatModule) it is giving me error "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dnndev.me/p3/signalr/hubs"

Can someone guide me here to the correct path

Comment: That regex you added to the AUM_DoNotRewiteRegEx for '/SignalR' is only for the path starting with /signalr.  For child portals, it doesn't appear to work.  I would try to see if you could maybe change the expression to include any child aliases before it.  Like maybe: /([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/SignalR

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: Kanishka, can you try this?  '/DesktopModules/|/Providers|/LinkClick\.aspx|/SignalR/|/p3/SignalR'

Comment: Already did.still not working